# Function not being read, displays full code instead data

Tags: html, angularjs, filter, html-table

I am trying to create an assignment filter that filters the array so that its linked to the Course ID, however, it seems that my function is not being read so when I look to see what's inside by using the curly brackets its just shows the code, not the actual assignment.

```js
$scope.myAssignmentFilter = function(){
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.filteredCourses.length; i++) {
      if ($scope.filteredCourses[i] === $scope.assignment.CourseID){
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false; 
  };
```

Comment: Can you add an example of how you use `myAssignmentFilter` in your html ?
Does it look like the following:  `{{ myAssignmentFilter() }}` ? Could it be that you are missing the brackets `()` ?

Comment: Yes I used {{myAssignmentFilter ()}}, but it just returns as false.

Comment: Can you add your html code. I assume that you want to display the list of filteredCourses. Function myAssignmentFilter  returns true or false and then is correct that shows you true or false, if you use it as {{ myAssignmentFilter() }}. You should apply your filter on some ng-repeat.